# Azure Traffic Manager with multiple web apps

Tags: azure, routes, azure-web-app-service, high-availability, azure-traffic-manager

I have two web apps, let's say API1 and WWW1 deployed on Azure.
these apps are deployed in the same azure region.

I would like to use high availability configured as active/passive with hot standby.

To achieve this I have replicated the apps in the paired region (API2 and WWW2) and I am creating a Traffic manager profile working in priority routing mode, and configure endpoints. More specifically I would like to configure that API1 is the primary endpoint and the API2 is the secondary. The same I would like to do with WWW1 and WWW2.

However I get an error because both the app (API1 and WWW1) are on the same azure region.

Do I need to configure two different Traffic manager profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would create multiple Traffic Manager profiles and then nest them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#a-name--performanceaperformance-traffic-routing-method

> "If your profile contains multiple endpoints in the same Azure region,
>   then Traffic Manager distributes traffic evenly across the available
>   endpoints in that region. If you prefer a different traffic
>   distribution within a region, you can use nested Traffic Manager
>   profiles."

How to [set up nested profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-nested-profiles).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be another option to setup two different TM profiles? (one for API1/API2 and the other for WWW1/WWW2)

Comment: Yes, the option of creating separate Traffic Manager profiles is also valid.

Comment: Traffic Manager will return a query response of type CNAME with the DNS name of the endpoint